# WARN [01-03|14:06:54.902] Block sealing failed err="unauthorized signer"

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain

```
{
  "config": {
    "chainId": 12345,
    "homesteadBlock": 0,
    "eip150Block": 0,
    "eip155Block": 0,
    "eip158Block": 0,
    "byzantiumBlock": 0,
    "constantinopleBlock": 0,
    "petersburgBlock": 0,
    "istanbulBlock": 0,
    "berlinBlock": 0,
    "clique": {
      "period": 5,
      "epoch": 30000
    }
  },
  "difficulty": "1",
  "gasLimit": "8000000",
  "extradata": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007df9a875a174b3bc565e6424a0050ebc1b2d1d820000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "alloc": {
    "7df9a875a174b3bc565e6424a0050ebc1b2d1d82": { "balance": "300000" },
    "f41c74c9ae680c1aa78f42e5647a62f353b7bdde": { "balance": "400000" }
  }
}
```

```
geth --datadir data --networkid 12345 --mine --miner.etherbase=0x05fc8ae572a7776c6547aa73663c0b1835c2f2f6  --signer=/home/xu/.clef/clef.ipc console
```

```
miner.start()
INFO [01-03|14:06:54.901] Legacy pool tip threshold updated        tip=1,000,000,000
INFO [01-03|14:06:54.901] Snap sync complete, auto disabling
null
> INFO [01-03|14:06:54.902] Commit new sealing work                  number=1 sealhash=f71296..2937d2 txs=0 gas=0 fees=0 elapsed="216.707µs"
WARN [01-03|14:06:54.902] Block sealing failed                     err="unauthorized signer"
```